# Multi-page scrapy yielding my items too quickly to finish - functions not chaining and waiting for completion

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm making a soccer app trying to wrap my head around how multi page scraping works.

For example, on the first page (http://footballdatabase.com/ranking/world/1) is 2 sets of links I want to scrape: the club name link, and pagination links

I want to go through **a)** every page (pagination), then **b)** go through each club and grab its current eu ranking.

The code I've written works, somewhat. However I end up with only around 45 results instead of the 2000+ clubs. --Note: There are 45 pages of pagination. So it appears as soon as it has looped through that everything finishes and my item is yielded.

How can I make it all chain together so I end up with more like 2000+ results?

Here is my code

```
# get Pagination links
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css("ul.pagination > li > a::attr('href')"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_club)

# get club links on each of the pagination pages
def parse_club(self, response):


    # loop through each of the rows
    for sel in response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr'):

        item = rankingItem()

            item['name'] = sel.xpath('td/a/div[@class="limittext"]/text()').extract()

            # get more club information
            club_href = sel.xpath('td[2]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()  
            club_url = response.urljoin(club_href) 
            request = scrapy.Request(club_url,callback=self.parse_club_page_2)

            request.meta['item'] = item
            return request

# get the EU ranking on each of the club pages
def parse_club_page_2(self,response):

    item = response.meta['item']
    item['eu_ranking'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="label label-default"][2]/text()').extract() 

    yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `yield` from the `parse_club` callback - not `return`:

```
# get club links on each of the pagination pages
def parse_club(self, response):
    # loop through each of the rows
    for sel in response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr'):    
        item = rankingItem()    
        item['name'] = sel.xpath('td/a/div[@class="limittext"]/text()').extract()

        # get more club information
        club_href = sel.xpath('td[2]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()  
        club_url = response.urljoin(club_href) 
        request = scrapy.Request(club_url,callback=self.parse_club_page_2)

        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request  # FIX HERE
```

---

I would also simplify the element locating part to:

```
def parse_club(self, response):
    # loop through each of the rows
    for sel in response.css('td.club'):
        item = rankingItem()
        item['name'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="itemListElement"]/text()').extract_first()

        # get more club information
        club_href = sel.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        club_url = response.urljoin(club_href)
        request = scrapy.Request(club_url, callback=self.parse_club_page_2)

        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
```

Comment: I think it goes without saying, in my mind, you are a God. I was ready to rewrite the whole thing.